# Javascript: Merging Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, nested-object, nest-nested-object

I have an array of objects with nested object, as shown below:

```
[
  {
    "metric1": 4.1,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_1": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb2",
      "ThisDN_1": "50002",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  },
  {
    "metric2": -12345.123412341234,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_2": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb3",
      "ThisDN_2": "50003",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  },
  {
    "metric3": -2345.123412341234,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_1": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb2",
      "ThisDN_1": "50002",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  },
  {
    "metric4": -345.12341234123414,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_2": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb3",
      "ThisDN_2": "50003",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to merge some of the array objects with the same nested object `addons`, so that the previous array becomes:

```
[
  {
    "metric1": 4.1,
    "metric3": -2345.123412341234,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_1
": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb2",
      "ThisDN_1": "50002",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  },
  {
    "metric2": -12345.123412341234,
    "metric4": -345.12341234123414,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_2": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb3",
      "ThisDN_2": "50003",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  }
]
```

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: `call_uuid_l`("l" instead of "1") is this a typo, or are keys not the same as each other?

Comment: Why would you not want to use `lodash`, It's treeshakable and its core build is currently only [~4kb](https://lodash.com/)?

Comment: @yessir it was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I had thought that it has vulnerabilities, but just found that the latest version(v4,17.21) is OK (https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/lodash). A bit pity that it is not actively maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array has more than one element with the same `addons` object, you can delete the first one's `addons` object and then merge it with the others.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(arr[i]["addons"]) === JSON.stringify(arr[j]["addons"])) {
      delete arr[i]["addons"];
      Object.assign(arr[i], arr[j]);
      arr.splice(j, 1);
      j -= 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    metric1: 4.1,
    metric3: -2345.123412341234,
    addons: {
      call_uuid_1: '13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb2',
      ThisDN_1: '50002',
      call_uuid: '13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4',
      ThisDN: '50004'
    }
  },
  {
    metric2: -12345.123412341234,
    metric4: -345.12341234123414,
    addons: {
      call_uuid_2: '13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb3',
      ThisDN_2: '50003',
      call_uuid: '13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4',
      ThisDN: '50004'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @yessir, straight forward one, I optimize a little bit by changing the 2nd for loop to start from i+1. Also I use `lodash` finally after finding out that there is no other alternation. (sorry for that, I have removed the restriction from the post.

Comment: @KenTsoi Add `j -= 1` at the end of the `if` block if you'll use 'i+1', or it doesn't work if the array has more than four objects.

Comment: Good catch for the `j-=1`, but why it doesn't work if the array has more than 4 objects?

Comment: BTW, I am using `lodash.isequal`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isequal) to avoid loading the whole lodash package.

Comment: @KenTsoi `splice()` remove elements from the array, so if you don't use the `j -= 1` index will continue to increase while the array length decreases.

Comment: yes I understand that, but why 4 objects?

Comment: My bad, it's not about 4 objects. Not works if there are more than 2 elements(at least 3) in a row with the same `addons` object. Because it skips the next object. When you're checking the 4th array element if it's the same as another one you will splice it. Now array length decreased while your `j` increased. You have to check the same index again because the 5th element is now the 4th.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to look for equality in the `addons` object and then merge your objects. Like this:

```
const array = [
  {
    "metric1": 4.1,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_1": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb2",
      "ThisDN_1": "50002",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  },
  {
    "metric2": -12345.123412341234,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_2": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb3",
      "ThisDN_2": "50003",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  },
  {
    "metric3": -2345.123412341234,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_1": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb2",
      "ThisDN_1": "50002",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  },
  {
    "metric4": -345.12341234123414,
    "addons": {
      "call_uuid_2": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb3",
      "ThisDN_2": "50003",
      "call_uuid": "13d1e097-0363-4a81-b9e4-85c6a770cdb4",
      "ThisDN": "50004"
    }
  }
];

const mergedArray = [];
const addonsToIndexMap = {};

array.forEach(item => {
 const stringifyAddon = JSON.stringify(item.addons);    
 let indexInTheMap = addonsToIndexMap[stringifyAddon];
 if(indexInTheMap !== undefined) {
   mergedArray[indexInTheMap] = {...mergedArray[indexInTheMap], ...item};
 } else {
   mergedArray.push(item);
   addonsToIndexMap[stringifyAddon] = mergedArray.length - 1;
 }
});
console.log(mergedArray);
```

The use of `addonsToIndexMap` is just for optimization purposes.
**Note:** This method only works if the order of keys within the `addon` objects is the same.
Also, I rectified the input in my program to update the key `call_uuid_l` with `call_uuid_1` to get the expected output, as mentioned in the comments. Please modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @charchitkapoor for the effort. I finally use `lodash` after finding out that there is no other alternation. (sorry for that, I have removed the restriction from the post.